# Is there an efficient string matching algorithm in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, string-matching

Is there an implementation of a fast string matching algorithm for searching keywords in MySQL? For example [Aho-Corasick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) or any other fast string matching algorithm.

Typically Aho-Corasick is implemented in Java or any other compiled language but it should be possible to write it as a stored procedure in MySQL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stored procedures are turing-complete, and you can use a "cursor" to loop through the records in a table (possibly with some existing "WHERE" cause), then you can do it in a stored procedure.

A stored function would also be possible.

However, the MySQL stored-routine language is so terrible both in terms of programmer-usability and performance, that the result is unlikely to be easy or fast.

So you might be better off writing a MySQL UDF (which you can write in any language, provided you can make it look like a C library) and having that do it instead.

Consider your specific requirements. I am assuming that a query with lots of "OR col LIKE ..." tagged together is too inefficient for you, as you wish to match thousands of patterns at once, right?